# html canvas: clipping and text

Tags: html, canvas, clip

I'm working on a paint app using canvas,
and i want to let the user the option to draw only in a selected area.
for that I can use the clip() method.
but if I want the user to be able to draw inside letters also - is there any way to use clip() for text?
is there another way I can do it?

thanks

Comment: I cannot understand "but if I want the user to be able to draw inside letters also " part

Answer (score 13):

You can do this but not using clip. Clip only works with paths and text is not a path.

You will need to use a second in-memory (not on the page) canvas in order to achieve the effect. Here is how:

1. Make an in-memory canvas, set it to a width and height capable of containing the text
2. Draw the text to that in-memory canvas
3. set the in-memory context's globalCompositeOperation to 'source-in'
4. Draw the thing you want clipped to the text
5. use `drawImage(in-memory-canvas, x, y)` to put the newly created effect onto your normal canvas

Comment: well, it's making some problems. when I draw the "clipped" text with a less than 100% alpha color, I can't draw the same pixels again with a higher alpha % color.